middleWare protect function not working as expected
I have been following a guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wlxx3SCHZKk&t=10255s&ab_channel=ZinoTrustAcademy ,
As I'm trying to learn about MERNs, but when it gets to the implementation of a "protect" function, a function that will detect if you are logged in in order to use the different functions other that log in or register. It just doesnt work.
This is my protect Function: 

// authMiddleWare.js
const protect = asyncHandler(async(req,res,next)=>{
    try {
        const token = req.cookies.token;
        if (!token) {
            res.status(401)
            throw new Error("Not autorized, Please log in!")
        }
        // Verify token
    const verified = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    user = await FuncionarioMedico.findById(verified.id).select('-password');
    if (!user) {
        res.status(401)
        throw new Error("User not found!");
    }
    req.funcionarioMedico = user;
    next();

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(401);
        throw new Error("Not authorized, Please login!")
    }
    
})

module.exports = protect;


//This is my route:
router.get("/getFuncionario",protect, getFuncionario)
//This is the function that Gets called after the Protect: That will get me my Data:
//Get funcionario Data
const getFuncionario = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    // Retrieve funcionario data
    const funcionario = await FuncionarioMedico.findById(req.funcionario._id);

    if (funcionario) {
        // Destructure funcionario properties
        const {_id, name, email, image, phone} = funcionario;
        res.status(200).json({
            _id,
            name,
            email,
            image,
            phone
        });
    } else {
        res.status(400);
        throw new Error("Invalid Username or Password!");
    }
});

I am not sure where the problem is since I am strictly following the guide, I am fairly new in using APIs CRUDs. Which is to say, I don't know what I am doing.
This proyect has academic purposes and in order to test it I must use Thunder Client, So using insomnia for the testing was out of the question.
After the log in and the Register regardless if theres a token present it will just throw me the error: "Not authorized, Please Login!", as If there is none. I am not sure If I did anything wrong or is just a testing bug since as I said I am using Thunder Client.
Full Code in case is necessary: https://github.com/yzkael/homeWorkMERN
Aside from the error present I will appreciate any feedback Since I am really diggin into MERNs!

There's no point in your catch clause, so remove that. Do you still have the error after?

You should get the token from the Bearer Token field in the headers. Here is the code that could help.
exports.protect = catchAsyncError(async (req, res, next) => {
  let token; // get token sent by the user
  if (
    req.headers.authorization &&
    req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer") // check if the token exists
  ) {
    token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
  } else {
    return next(
      new AppError(404, `You're not logged in. Please login to access.`)
    ); // token is invalid or token is not present
  }

  const { id } = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY); // decode and get id

  if (!id) { 
    return next(
      new AppError(404, `You're not authorized to access the resource`)
    );
  }

  const user = await AllUsers.findById(id).select("+otp password");

  if (!user) {
    return next(
      new AppError(404, `No user found.`)
    );
  }

  req.user = user;
  next();
});

